# How can I get excel to run VBA code in response to the user pressing the ESCAPE key?

Tags: excel

The code I am using is below.  When the user double clicks a cell with no value, the code enters today's date, the cell keeps the focus and the cursor is inside the cell allowing the user to edit the value.  However, if the user presses the ESCAPE key, the cell keeps today's date.   I'd like it to restore the value that was in the cell before the user double clicked on the cell.  Which is how it usually behaves if the user enters data into a blank cell.

I understand that the undo stack is cleared when VBA runs and that programming can be used to store and restore changed values eg [here](http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/undowithvba00.asp)

However, how can I get excel to respond to the user pressing the ESCAPE key?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Not (Intersect(Target, Me.Range("shtJobList2_Columns_EnterDateOnCellDoubleClick")) Is Nothing) Then

        ' User double clicked in a column of interest

        If Not (Intersect(Target, Me.Range("TableOfJobs2")) Is Nothing) Then

            ' User double click in the table as well!

            If IsEmpty(Target.Value) Then

                Target.Value = Date
                Beep

            Else

                If vbOK = MsgBox("Do you want to enter todays date over the value that is already in the cell?  (" & Target.Value & ")", vbOKCancel) Then
                    Target.Value = Date
                End If

            End If

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify a few points:

1. The *undo stack* is not cleared until VBA *changes a value*. You can use use `Application.Undo`, store the previous value, then `Application.Redo` and ask for confirmation. (click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27085262/scan-multiple-barcodes-into-a-single-excel-cell-each-on-a-separate-line) for example)
2. If you are implementing `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick`, do not discard the *Cancel As Boolean* parameter as unimportant. Setting *Cancel* to *True* halts the *Edit in cell* process. It seems awkward to be entering edit mode for every double-click (date insertion) rather than editing the minority where the current date is not appropriate. I say minority because the whole process is pretty useless if the current date is not what is desired the majority of the time.

Alternative:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    'Intersect can have more than two paramteters
    If Not (Intersect(Target, _
                      Me.Range("shtJobList2_Columns_EnterDateOnCellDoubleClick"), _
                      Me.Range("TableOfJobs2")) Is Nothing) Then
        ' User double clicked in a column of interest and the table
        If IsEmpty(Target) Then
            Cancel = True
            Target.Value = Date
            Beep
        Else
            If vbOK = MsgBox("Do you want to enter todays date over the value that is already in the cell?  (" & Target.Value & ")", vbYesNo) Then
                Cancel = True
                Target.Value = Date
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

That alters the process flow you had originally demonstrated by setting *Cancel = True* in a couple of places. Perhaps you can use this to get the results you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Application.OnKey*  to detect the press of the **ESCAPE** key, but only if your are not in *edit* mode.